# Weird interaction with using variables as arguments in a method call

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im wondering if somebody could please explain to me why does the left side not work but right side does? Why does assigning the radiuses to variables first produce the wrong calculation in the end?

[image: The code]

Comment: Please paste your code here as text, not as an image.

Comment: Enough code to see and test fixes to your problem -- a [mre] -- should be included **as text** in the question itself. See also [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) -- we can't copy/paste code from a screenshot to run it ourselves or test a proposed fix.

Comment: You should not name your variable `area` or you will shadow your class method of the same name.

Comment: BTW, welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. You can [edit] the question, copy the text itself, and use [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 0):

Look at line 9 of each of the two codes you posted. On the left side, you are doing `26 / 2`, whereas on the right side you do `36 / 2` …

Comment: Holy crap I was so confused, and I asked other people and nobody noticed it in the code either. Thank you so much